# Limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi}} \int_{t}^{+ \infty} \sqrt{z} e^{-z(1 - 2 \sqrt{y} + y)} y^{1/4} dy$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

What is the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi}} \int_{t}^{+ \infty} \sqrt{z} e^{-z(1 - 2 \sqrt{y} + y)} y^{1/4} dy$ when $z \rightarrow + \infty $ ?

If $t > 1$, by the dominated convergence theorem, the limit should be 0.
But there is a problem when $y=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The substitution $y=\big(1+w/\sqrt{z}\big)^2$ transforms it into
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{\sqrt{z}(\sqrt{t}-1)}^{+\infty}\big(1+w/\sqrt{z}\big)^{3/2}e^{-w^2}\,dw,$$
making the limit (again by DCT) seen to be
$$\big(1+\operatorname{sgn}(1-t)\big)/2=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }t<1\\1/2&\text{if }t=1\\0&\text{if }t>1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! When you make the right substitution, everything becomes much easier!